# Is there a open source framework which simplifies working with Audio Units?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio, audiounit

I just need an IO Unit with a processing callback with a simple play and stop feature.

Apple has this giant MixerHost demo with thousands of lines of code just to play two mixed audio files.

It seems 99% of that code is boilerplate to set things up.

Maybe there is a open source framework which deals with this boilerplate such that you can just set up your Audio Session and start constructing a simple processing graph with an IO Unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Novocaine](http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/), an analgesic for high-performance audio on the iPhone, iPad and Mac OS X. Really fast audio in iOS and Mac OS X using Audio Units is hard, and will leave you scarred and bloody. What used to take days can now be done with just a few lines of code.

Comment: This sounds like a shameless plug

Comment: @NikReiman perhaps so, but I think that marketing-type responses don't belong on a programmer's site.  It would be more helpful to the OP to post the link and a short code sample.

Comment: @sbooth, I disagree in this case, especially because the question is specifically asking for framework recommendations and because the answer here isn't even from the framework author. If it is a plug, well, that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @sbooth Sorry to trouble you to think I'm a spam. I found Novocaine in Github and just post a link here. I didn't test it yet, but it looks like a good framework from its docs.

Comment: It sounds like a shameless plug because that's the blurb I wrote on the github page for Novocaine.

Comment: @alexbw what's the advantage of using novocaine over the audio queue renderer? I was using the audio queue renderer until i reached a part where debugging/modifying my code required to use a lower level api for audio processing in iOS.. which is Audio Units.. i know that novocaine also uses audio units, but by providing this level of abstraction.. isn't also taking away from one of the advantages of using audio units?

Comment: Novocaine's sole purpose is to get you access to raw audio samples fast. If you need to do fancy hook-ups like 3D mixers, reverb or samplers, then Novocaine is probably not the right choice, and you'll want to get your hands dirty with low-level Core Audio.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit to @fannheyward's answer, [Novocaine](http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/) is definitely the way to go. The key advantage is that you can pass in an objective-C block which will be executed each time the audio subsystem is ready to process a block of audio. It abstracts away most of the difficult boilerplate code, and lets you focus on the DSP.